# display the text of div element on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few div elements in my code and I need to display the text of every div element on hover in the page corner. I've added onmouseover to every div and tried to make a script. So, this is what I have reached since now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<title> Periodic Table </title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showMore(){
document.getElementsByClassName("number").innerHTML = /* div txt here */
document.getElementsByClassName("electroneg").innerHTML = /* div txt here */
document.getElementsByClassName("couch").innerHTML = /* div txt here */
document.getElementsByClassName("symbol").innerHTML = /* div txt here */
document.getElementsByClassName("name").innerHTML = /* div txt here */
document.getElementsByClassName("massatom").innerHTML = /* div txt here */
} 
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div onmouseover="showMore()" class="elementChim left">
        <div class="number">1</div>
        <div class="electroneg">2,1</div>
        <div class="couch">
            <div>1</div>
        </div>  
        <div class="symbol gaz">H</div>
        <div class="name">Hydrogen</div>
        <div class="massatom">1,0088</div>
    </div>

    <div onmouseover="showMore()" class="elementChim right">
        <div class="number">2</div>
        <div class="symbol gaz">He</div>
        <div class="name">Helium</div>
        <div class="masseatom">4,002</div>
        <div class="electroneg"></div>
        <div class="couch">
            <div>2</div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if it's ok to use innerHTML everytime. Can anyone offer some insights?

I'd like to get something like [this](http://www.dreamwv.com/primer/page/s_pertab.html) as result.

But I only need to display the text of every div element in the page corner.

Many thanks!

Comment: can you provide css also? or load your project to https://jsfiddle.net please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you set `innerHTML` the browser has to parse what you set it as. That only matters if you are setting large amounts of text. If you don't need insert HTML you can use `textContent` instead.

To display the divs of data from the chemical element divs you could use `document.cloneNode` to make a copy of the elements inside of the chemical element divs and append them to the corner:

```js
var corner;
function showMore() {
  // Empty corner
  corner.innerHTML = "";
  // Go through the children of the moused over element
  for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
    // Clone and append them to the corner
    corner.appendChild(this.children[i].cloneNode(true));
  }
}

// When elements can be accessed
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Select chemical element elements
  var chemicalElementDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("elementChim");
  for (var i = 0; i < chemicalElementDivs.length; i++) {
    // Add listeners to them
    chemicalElementDivs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", showMore);
  }
  corner = document.getElementById("corner")
});
```

```css
.elementChim {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#corner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="elementChim left">
  <div class="number">1</div>
  <div class="electroneg">2,1</div>
  <div class="couch">
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="symbol gaz">H</div>
  <div class="name">Hydrogen</div>
  <div class="massatom">1,0088</div>
</div>

<div class="elementChim right">
  <div class="number">2</div>
  <div class="symbol gaz">He</div>
  <div class="name">Helium</div>
  <div class="masseatom">4,002</div>
  <div class="electroneg"></div>
  <div class="couch">
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="corner"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it now

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTML-title Attribute.

```
<div title="Your mouseover-Text here"></div>
```

Or if you want to solve this with JavaScript you can look up the

**createElement()** - Method

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using only the CSS `:hover` selector like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="number">
    <span>1</span>
</div>

<div class="electroneg">
    <span>2,1</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.number span {opacity:0;}
.number:hover span {opacity:1;}

.electroneg span {opacity:0;}
.electroneg:hover span {opacity:1;}
```

---

**jsFiddle** with above codes: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/be2hqqwx/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use JS. Thank you so much for this example.